# How to use the test user's account for real purchase when the app is in production for puchasing the same product?

Tags: android, android-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I have developed an app with billing purchase.

I have list of test user account in google play console and I can purchase as a test user(alpha release).

Everything is fine in test purchase. Now I have released the app in production. I want to purchase the same product which I was purchased as a test user.My problem is I can't purchase the same product via the same google account. It throws "*Item already owned*" error message.

Answer (score 0):

Products without subscription must be consumed after receipt.

```
mBillingManager.consumeAsync(purchase.getPurchaseToken());
```